# A Docker container with an instance of Bamboo server closes exposed port

Tags: docker, bamboo

I have an issue regarding a Bamboo Server running in a Docker container, recently an exposed port which is used by multiple Bamboo Remote Agents closes on its own (no pattern) and the Agents aren't able to connect to the Server. It's a JMS port - 54663.

A restart of the Docker daemon helps, but I need to find the root cause of the issue. Any suggestions where to start looking?

Thank you very much in advance!